# How to know what keeps a node process from stopping?

Tags: node.js

I hace a pretty complex script, which opens sockets, HTTP servers, reads/writes to files, sets timeouts etc. Upon reaching some conditions all of these should stop - I'm clearing all the timeouts, closing all the servers and so on.

But sometimes the process stops fine, and sometimes it just keeps waiting for something to happen. I can kill the node process, but I'd like to find out the cause of that behavior, fix it and have the process stop by itself. Is it possible to debug what keeps it from exiting?

**Update:**

I followed Jan's suggestion and this I what I got when I tried "debugging" a simple `setTimeout` call:

```
/tmp/node2/bin/node test.js 
[debug] UV_TIMER   0x1cdfd20 (fd:910168617, refs:0, flags:0x0)
[debug] UV_ASYNC   0xc096e8 (fd:0, refs:-1, flags:0x0)
[debug] UV_ASYNC   0xc09658 (fd:0, refs:0, flags:0x0)
[debug] UV_IDLE    0xc09778 (fd:0, refs:-2, flags:0x0)
[debug] UV_ASYNC   0xc041c0 (fd:0, refs:-1, flags:0x0)
[debug] UV_ASYNC   0xc03de0 (fd:0, refs:-1, flags:0x0)
[debug] UV_TIMER   0xc03d40 (fd:0, refs:-1, flags:0x0)
[debug] UV_IDLE    0xc03ca0 (fd:0, refs:-1, flags:0x0)
[debug] UV_CHECK   0xc03c00 (fd:0, refs:-1, flags:0x0)
[debug] UV_IDLE    0xc03a00 (fd:0, refs:-1, flags:0x0)
[debug] UV_CHECK   0xc03b60 (fd:0, refs:-1, flags:0x0)
[debug] UV_PREPARE 0xc03ac0 (fd:0, refs:-1, flags:0x0)
```

So this is not very useful for me, but I guess there are no other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easy. You can compile [this patched version](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node/compare/print-handles) of node.js, start your application with it (`node appname.js`) and then run:

```
pkill -USR2 node
```

This will print out all the active handles on the event loop at that moment.

---

N.B. this is a four month old version so it's a bit out of date. It should go into node at one point but no plans yet.

Comment: Done this, but the only thing that gets printed is "User defined signal 2" and then the process exits.

Comment: Disregard that, I should have switched to the other branch before compiling